# How does WordPress know when there are plugin updates?

Tags: plugins, plugin-repository

How does a WordPress plugin know whether if there are updates available to download and to download those updates. What function or script controls this and how does it work?

I am assuming this would be the same function that controls whether a plugin has been purchased aka premium or has not been purchased and how do product keys work?

I want to find out because I want to dive into creating my own plugin.

Comment: WordPress sends a check to the wordpress.org repository. Have you really not found anything? We have covered this dozens of times here.

Comment: This answer should clear up some of your issues: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214396/do-uploaded-plugins-get-updates-if-they-came-from-the-wordpress-plugin-directory/214412#214412

Comment: @toscho not hundreds yet?

Comment: I also must say, great edit to this question, I may answer it tomorrow in some length due to how direct it has become.

Comment: Thank you guys, if it has been covered and I could not find it then I am sorry. I will check the links now.